# When to use "she's"(short form) and and "she is"(full form)? What is the difference?

Tags: pronouns

Example : He isn't tired but she is. Why can't use "she's"? Why is "she is" used?

Comment: The difference is that _she's_ and similar shortened forms are used in colloquial speech, but _not_ in certain cases. In your example, _she_ is being emphasised.

Comment: Short form can stand for, say, She's a good student; She's got good memory,  (She is... & She has...), whereas, 'She is...' can have only single interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would ever be proper to end a sentence with "she's" (see the link @JR posted as a comment to your question for a detailed explanation).

Other than that, the contraction can be used interchangeably. Good to note though that contractions are generally more informal/colloquial. So maybe you would say to you friend "She's my supervisor." But in a formal work report, you might say "She is my supervisor."